# Deleting Service Endpoint in Visual Studio

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-web-app-service, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-devops-rest-api

We are doing some testing using the Continuous Deployment feature of Azure Web Apps, which created a Service Endpoint in our corresponding visualstudio.com account.

We deleted the Web App we were testing with before deleting the service endpoint and now when we go to delete the service endpoint it won't let us because it can't find the web app.

How can we get this service endpoint object removed from our visualstudio.com account?

Comment: Do you solve the issue with my way?

Comment: @starianchen-MSFT yes, resolved issue with steps you provided.  Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The workaround is that you can create a new Azure Web App with the same name, then you can delete the service endpoint.

There is the feedback that you can vote: [VSTS can't delete service endpoint that created through Azure Web App Continuous Delivery](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/234399/vsts-cant-delete-service-endpoint-that-created-thr.html)